# Comparing the elements in memory game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's my first steps with programming in js.

I've problem with compare elements in memory game.

After clicking, the code compares only one element from the first click and it causes the function and does not compare further elements despite the collected value -

For example: if I click `img` with `src="f1.png"`, it's comparing only that element with that same `src`, not comparing other elements. Here it's `f2.png`
(This can be confusing but I don't know how to best to describe it)

Please, help me fix that problem.

> html

```
  <div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"><img src="f1.png" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"><img src="f2.png" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"><img src="f1.png" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b"><img src="f2.png" /></div>
  </div>
```

> script

```
(function() {
    var open = "";
    var cards = $(".c.ef");
    for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var card = cards[i];
        clickListener(card);
    }

    function clickListener(card) {
        card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
            var c = this.classList;
            c.add("flip");
            var open1="";
            if(open == ""){
                open = $( ".flip" ).contents().find("img").attr("src");
            }else{
                open1 = $( ".flip" ).contents().find("img").attr("src");
            }
            if(open !== open1){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    c.remove("flip"); 
                }, 1200);
            }else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".flip").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    c.remove("flip");
                }, 800);
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: what  are you trying  to do?

Comment: i try compare first element with second element after click on div with img and if that same change visibility to hidden else compare next two elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to describ how i will proceded

1rst : you can use data attribute for manipulate easier dom img
2nd : save data value in variable when you click on image
3rd : compare if you second click match with your first variable

so e.g :

```
<div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b" data-img-value="1"><img src="f1.png"  /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b" data-img-value="2"><img src="f2.png" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b" data-img-value="1"><img src="f1.png" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="c ef">
    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="b" data-img-value="2"><img src="f2.png" /></div>
  </div>
```

------------------- script----------

```
 (function() {
      var $card= $('.b');
      var $firstVal = null;
      $card.on('click',function(){
      if($firstVal === null){
          $firstVal = $(this).first().attr('data-img-value');
      }
      else{
        if($firstVal === $(this).first().attr('data-img-value')){
           //your code if pair match
           console.log('pair founded')
           $firstval = null;
        }
        else{
             //your code if not match
            console.log('not pair')

        }
      }

   });
})();
```

you can run this exemple here

https://jsfiddle.net/a1na9hLe/5/

Answer (score 0):

After the comparison was made, you have to reset `open` in order to make a new comparison.

After the first click, `open` is set to, for example, "f1.png". (btw, imo, you should return here).
After the second click, `open1` is set to, for example, "f2.png".
Then the comparison `open !== open1` gives you a result, but you never reset `open` back to `""`.
So, for the third click, open is already set to the previous value ("f1.png"), and it'll compare the same thing again and again.

TL;DR

This should do the trick:

`if(open !== open1){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    c.remove("flip"); 
                    open = '';
                }, 1200);
            }else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".flip").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    c.remove("flip");
                    open = '';
                }, 800);
            }`

Comment: It is better but hides only the second clicked element, 
the first remains visible

Comment: That's because you're doing this: `c.remove("flip");`, while `c` is the last clicked element. You should re-query flipped elements or something.